# Convert png/jpg to urf/pwg-raster to print it through IPP

Tags: node.js, image, printing

I'm trying to print using NodeJS some PDF file to an IP printer through [IPP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipp).
However, my print only supports these document format:

- application/octet-stream
- image/urf
- image/pwg-raster

There're plenty of methods of converting the PDF to an image, but I'm not sure how can I convert that image (png/jpg) to image/urf - image/pwg-raster codification to be able to print it.

Any tips?

Comment: `application/octet-stream` basically means a stream of bytes and not any format in particular. Have you tried sending it a jpeg or png (or even the pdf)?

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Yeah, I've tried sending the PDF and a JPG with "application/octet-stream", but it printed ASCI lines instead of the file itself

Comment: Ah, too bad. Well image/urf seems to be an Apple specific format which isn't public so I think means it is a dead end. image/pwg-raster might be fesable, I would try with a tool such as https://istopwg.github.io/ippsample/ipptransform.html or check their source for how to do the conversion.

Comment: Are you by any chance attempting to print to an Amazon Smart Sticky Note printer or a similar thermal printer?

Answer (score 2):

While making a printing app, i found myself needing to do exactly that.
And like you, found mostly nothing.
So i made my own, available as standalone utilities here: https://github.com/attah/ppm2pwg/

pdf2printable from there can do pdf to pwg or urf raster directly (they are pretty much the same format).

Also; application/octet-stream just means auto-detect. And apart from the odd broken implementation listing only that, and Postscript printer with bonus PDF support, that is only between the other formats listed.

Answer (score 1):

Apple raster (image/urf) and PWG raster (image/pwg-raster) are standard Page Description Languages (PDLs) capable of being output by CUPS. Debian provides **ippeveprinter**. It can be invoked by

```
/usr/sbin/ippeveprinter -d $HOME/Downloads/ -f image/urf myprinter
```

A PDF submitted to the printiing system and sent to **myprinter** is obliged to produce an Apple raster file, which is put into. *$HOME/Downloads/*. It can be sent directly to your printer, perhaps by using the -c option with a script.